# MacBookPro's temperature increases dramatically with 10.8.2 update

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro

After updating MacOS from 10.8.1 to 10.8.2, it's heating obvious.

I do nothing, but chrome is stopping at the page of reader. Temp is 77 DC and more.
Why, why my 2012 mid MBP 13's temp is higher than before?

Comment: Why not run "`top`" from the Terminal command line and see what's causing the CPU to be so busy that you could fry an egg on the keyboard?

Comment: Thanks . The egg is the ParentalController, stopping all users' parentalcontroller, temp is back to 50 DC again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Activity Monitor to find out which processes have a lot of CPU usage.  If you find and process which seems unusually high, please post it here so we can provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot . The problem is the Parental Controller. 
From 10.8.1 to 10.8.2  ,and now 10.8.3 the problem is still here.
By looking the "top" command , I stopped all users' parentalcontroller ,then the temp was get down.